# AFNetworking background file upload

Tags: objective-c, file-upload, afnetworking, background-process

I want to upload files to my server from my app.  The code below is working great when app is active. If I press home button or open another app uploading stops.

I activated background fetch but still not working.

Afnetworking has background support but I cant figure out how I implement this feature to my code.

```
NSString *str=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Archive.zip"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
     NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://url"
                                    parameters:parameters
                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                                     name:@"image"
                                                 fileName:@"Archive.zip"
                                                 mimeType:@"application/zip"];
                     }];


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                         NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     }];


    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];


    [operation start];
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: From apple NSURLSession document , background transfer support only upload and download tasks (no data tasks) with a file URL, According to your code it seems you are using NSData upload.

Answer (score 6):

Change this line

```
[operation start];
```

to this

```
[operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Handle iOS shutting you down (possibly make a note of where you
        // stopped so you can resume later)
    }];


    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

You can look at these links
[AFHTTPRequestOperation doesn't work after stand by mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375173/afhttprequestoperation-doesnt-work-after-stand-by-mode)
and [Alternative for enqueueHTTPRequestOperation in AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850800/alternative-for-enqueuehttprequestoperation-in-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: it stops after a couple of minutes if app is not active.

Comment: @charty: means when app is suspended by iOS ?